# how to insert multiple rows in a table in oracle 10G?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

i m creating a script which will insert multiple data in a table in one shot.

```
create table emp
(
Empno number(3) primary key,
ename varchar2(20),
job varchar2(20),
MGR varchar2(20),
sal varchar2(20)
);


insert all
into emp values(100,'Dinesh','President',NULL,50000);
into emp values(101,'Tanveer','MGR',100,25000);
into emp values(102,'Tejas','Developer',101,12000);
select * from dual
```

however above insert command is giving error

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Above code is correct but something is incorrect,plz help me to find out.

Comment: ";"s after each of the "into emp" lines.

Comment: Too localized.  The question is asking to correct a syntax error-- that's going to have very limited utility to anyone else.  

Comment: @JustinCave: I disagree. This is not simply a syntax error, the question is using multi-table instead of multi-row `INSERT`, which indicates real confusion. Furthermore, the syntax fix proposed by @PatrickMarchand results in a `0 rows inserted` message from Oracle, which does not achieve what the question is asking for. I've looked at the Oracle docs for `INSERT` and didn't see an example on how to do multi-row. IMO, the question is neither too localized, nor off-topic.

Comment: @JustinCave I am able to insert multiple row at one shot by using the help provided by Patrick..

Comment: @VadimK - It is perfectly legal to use the multi-table `INSERT ALL` syntax to insert multiple rows into a table.  `SQL> create table foo( col1 number );

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2    into foo values( 1 )
  3    into foo values( 2 )
  4   select *
  5     from dual;

2 rows created.`

Comment: @JustinCave: Thank you, I stand corrected. When I tried this at work, I received a `0 rows inserted` message, but now that I'm at home, I receive `3 rows inserted`. I must have done something wrong yesterday. At least I learned something new today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, a single-table `INSERT` can either specify a single `VALUES` clause or a sub-query. Since the task requires the insertion of multiple rows, the single `VALUES` clause won't work. A sub-query must be specified.

One simple way to generate the desired sub-query is to `SELECT` a sequence of literals from `dual` for each row and to collapse them all into a single table using the `UNION ALL` operator.

```
INSERT INTO emp ( empno, ename, job, mgr, sal )
    SELECT 100, 'Dinesh',  'President', NULL, 50000 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 101, 'Tanveer', 'MGR',       100,  25000 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 102, 'Tejas',   'Developer', 101,  12000 FROM dual;
```

Comment: please explain why your answer works and how you came to it so that others with similar but not identical problems can follow your reasoning and can understand how you got to the answer.

Comment: @ArtB: This isn't reasoning, it's (mostly) syntax. Explanation added.

Comment: @VadimK. Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Comment: @DineshSuthar: I've just cut and pasted this and I get `3 rows inserted.`